# What happens when the Recaptcha V2 quota limit is hit?

Tags: recaptcha

We are currently implementing the Recaptcha V2 and have concerns about reaching the monthly limit of 1 million calls. Can someone shed some light about what happens when this limit is reached?

Will a specific message be sent in the response or will the service just stop responding for instance?

Comment: I have reached the limit, and have not been limited on usage. I am wondering the same

Comment: Maybe you just will be billed

Comment: This is asking about the behavior of an API (a specific programming question), not asking for customer service.  The answer demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/quotas#:%7E:text=using%20that%20project.-,When%20you%20reach%20a%20quota%20limit,information%20about%20quota%20errors%20and%20status%20codes%2C%20see%20Quota%20errors.,-Rate%20and%20review).

> When you reach a quota limit When your API usage quotas exceed the specified quotas limit, any new request returns an HTTP error with status code.
>
> For more information about quota errors and status codes, see **Quota errors**.

And these are the [Quota errors](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#:%7E:text=and%20Cloud%20SQL.-,Quota%20errors,for%20specific%20quota%20errors%2C%20as%20described%20in%20Monitoring%20quota%20metrics.,-Except%20as%20otherwise).

> If your project exceeds a quota while using a service, Google Cloud returns an error based on how you accessed the service:
>
> - If you exceeded a quota with an HTTP/REST request, Google Cloud returns an HTTP 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS status code.
> - If you exceed a quota with an API request, Google Cloud returns an HTTP 413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE status code.
> - If you exceeded a quota using gRPC, Google Cloud returns a ResourceExhausted error. How this error appears to you depends on the service.
> - If you exceeded a quota using a gcloud command-line tool command, the gcloud tool outputs a quota-exceeded error message and returns with the exit code 1.
>
> Rate quotas reset after a predefined time interval that is specific to each service. For more information, see the quotas documentation for the specific service.
>
> If you want to be alerted when errors happen in future, you can create custom alerts for specific quota errors, as described in Monitoring quota metrics.