# Recaptcha V2 limit reached but is not being enforced, when will it?

Tags: recaptcha

I'm one of many who received a google V2 reCAPTCHA usage limit reached with a 90 day notice to reduce usage under the 1M free per month by purchasing enterprise or having limits enforced (message on your site stating it's "over limit" and every request passing).

However, it's now 105 days since that message, `FINAL NOTICE` was on June 2nd, and the limits aren't being enforced. It's July 13th, and I'm at 1.3M captchas for July.

**Has anyone received a limit reached email that has not had them enforced after the period?**

**When does the limit reset each month?** I'm assuming the 1st of the month, but I could be wrong.

PS: I'm not sure where else to ask this, but if this is the wrong forum I can move my question.

Comment: PSS: A similar question was asked last year with no answers or context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281923/recaptcha-v2-quota-limit

Comment: From a popular competitor of reCAPTCHA they said google will shut you off at some random point in the future. I don't know when this is, but I reduced my usage 80% since my initial notice, so I'm hoping to be able to continue to use it slightly over its limit like I am